# indicator-sound doesn't compile

Tags: indicator-sound, libdbusmenu

Currently i'm trying to get started with indicator development. To get a feel for it I want to play with indicator-sound but if i try to compile it i get the following message:

```
    configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.0
                           indicator3-0.4 >= 0.3.19
                           dbusmenu-gtk3-0.4 >= 0.5.90
                           libido3-0.1 >= 0.1.11
                           libnotify >= 0.7.0) were not met:

    No package 'dbusmenu-gtk3-0.4' found

    Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
    installed software in a non-standard prefix.

    Alternatively, you may set the environment variables APPLET_CFLAGS
    and APPLET_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
```

I already tried to install the package but it has the prefix "gir1.2-" and is not listed in pkg-config. I also tried to rename the package in the configure.ac file(But it doesn't work).

Is there a way to get it compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to download the source and build-dependencies as follows:

**first the prerequisite**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

**now get the source**

```
cd ~/Downloads
apt-get source indicator-sound
```

**install the development dependencies**

```
sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-sound
```

**how to compile**

Then you can compile using:

```
 cd indicator-sound-0.7.9/
./configure
make
```